# Appending date and time to filename

Tags: windows, file, cmd, cygwin

I would like to know how to append the date and time to a filename in Windows Cygwin environment through command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use touch command

> touch "YOUR_FILENAME.$(date)"

Answer (score 1):

What format of date and time do you want?  Try starting with this.

```
mv filename.txt filename$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').txt
```